# Location of crontab job created by non-privileged user

Tags: rhel, cron

The issue I currently have is someone has created a `crontab` process to run on a RHEL 5 box, yet has not left me any privileged user information.  How can I execute this `cron` job that was setup to run as user `foo` when I do not have `root` access?  Also of note this is a non-standard `cron` job insofar as it is run at arbitrary times.

Also where does this job get placed?  I have read that I should not attempt to modify anything that resides within `/var/spool` , which is fine since as I have stated I have no root access.

Comment: `crontab -e`, didnt ya know?

Comment: @poige no no I didn't know :(

Comment: Well, you should had tried `man cron` which in its "see also" mentions `man crontab` which in its turn answers all your question in depth.

Comment: @poige To be fair the man pages are ghastly and other searches on google netted very little information.  I asked this question to help future users that may have the same scenario (not everyone uses *nix on a daily basis)

Comment: IMO, there's no reason/needs to copy manual pages, that's not a way  to go anywhere except entropy increase. The first advice I was given when started my *NIX experience was "man pages rule, man". They still do, man.

Comment: @poige I will just answer my own question than.  From the FAQ: You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoking `crontab -e` when logged in as the specific user will open up that user's `crontab` file.  Edits can be made from that point forward.